# How to Post Google Forms Data via jQuery and Ajax to Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets

I'm working on a Chrome extension that's essentially a simple custom Google Form that will post to a response Spreadsheet. I got the following function to successfully send and populate data only once, but never again:

```
function postFormToGoogle() {
    var timeOne = $("#time1hour").val();
    var timeTwo = $('#time2hour').val();
    var timeThree = $('#time3hour').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORMKEY/formResponse",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID');
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
        },
        data: { "entry_856586387": timeOne, 
        "entry_244812041": timeTwo, 
        "entry_2138937452": timeThree },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        statusCode: {
            0: function () {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your form has been submitted!";
                window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
            },
            200: function () {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your form has been submitted!";
                console.log("Success");
                window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I had to include the cors request headers because I was getting a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' warning that blocked my request.

It being an extension, I also added the following permissions to the manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://docs.google.com",
  "https://docs.google.com",
  "https://*.google.com",
]
```

At this point, I'm not sure exactly what's preventing the data from posting. Possible indicators could be that when submitting the form I'm getting a "Provisional Headers are shown" caution and the server is taking way too long to respond as indicated by the Waiting (TTFB) time.

Where am I going wrong in the code? (It did work once, for some reason.) Any alternative solutions out there to post a custom form to Spreadsheets?

Comment: What's the `datatype` back from the server? Switch to `dataType: "html",` if it is `html`.

Comment: Indeed, the response header `content-type` from the server is `html`. I switched the 'dataType' accordingly, but data is still not populating. I'm no longer getting the "Provisional Headers are shown" caution for the header request though.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("message").innerText` instead of `document.getElementById("message").innerHTML`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr. Also do you implement Cross-Domain XHRs in Content scripts?

Comment: Turns out everything is fine with the code I shared. The main culprit was actually the `input` values on the html page. First I should point out that this form is using the Time Duration option on Google Forms, which has drop down menus for Hrs, Mins, and Secs. Digits 0 - 9 options had single digit values, when actually it's required that all values be double digits (01,02,etc.) in order for the request to be accepted. Thanks for your input, gui47.

Answer (score 8):

This is the way I did it... http://jsfiddle.net/adutu/7towwv55/1/
You can see that you receive a CORS error but it works... the data gets where it should be

```
        function postToGoogle() {
            var field3 = $('#feed').val();

            $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/[key]/formResponse",
            data: {"entry.347455363": field3},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            statusCode: {
                0: function() {
                    //Success message
                },
                200: function() {
                    //Success Message
                }
            }
        });
        }
```

See more info [here](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000)

Comment: CORS won't be a problem inside an extension

Comment: I can send data in that way but if I have more than one section in google form then how to send values of next section ?

Comment: This gets form data to my responses spreadsheet, but the CORS throws an error so I cannot do validation and success behaviors. The status code is 0 if it's a successful post and an unsuccessful post.