# Unable to handle scenario: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, google-forms

I have a form on a webpage which I'm using to capture data and post to a Google Form. The code I've used I saw on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267773/how-to-post-google-forms-data-via-jquery-and-ajax-to-spreadsheets). Now, as expected, I'm receiving an error like the following:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/.../formResponse.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

My script making the request is as follows:

```
function postToGoogle() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/.../formResponse",
    data: {"entry.1691469052": "test message"},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function() {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        postToGoogle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now even though I get the error, my data still persists to the form which is the outcome I want.

The issue I'm facing is that in the event that data is passed, I want to display a message to the user saying the data was received. What I'm trying to do is either:

1. fix the error through using CORS or similar (methods I'm not familiar with and can't find an answer for on SO)
2. somehow check within my 'error' function that the only issue is the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` one and then produce a 'success' message in that scenario. If there are other issues I'll just throw an 'error' message back to the user

So far I've not been able to find something that works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Same-origin policy won't prevent you from sending the request, but only from receiving the response.

Comment: You can't use CORS to send requests to a website over which you have no control.

Comment: @Gothdo, I know - my request is working fine and I'm seeing the form submission. What I'd like to do is treat this scenario as a 'success' - is there a way I can do that where I'll still be able to capture any other errors returned in the event the request doesn't succeed?

Comment: Read this : `http://stackoverflow.com/a/20434788/6106583`

Comment: *"somehow check within my 'error' function"* => why can't you do that ?

Comment: @Ilya because I'm unsure what I'm looking for. Is there a way I can do something like `if X == No Access-Control... then do something`?

Comment: You don't know how to get the error text ?

Comment: @Ilya no, I can't get the specific text that says something like `No-Access...` in order to do a comparison

Comment: Can you try `error: function(xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr); console.log(status); console.log(err); }` and see if you get better information?

Comment: @whipdancer unfortunately that doesn't give me any useful information

Comment: do any of those simply output `object` to the console? or all empty strings? or `undefined`?

Comment: Nm, I just read @Jako's response below.  Not what I would have thought.

Answer (score 0):

See the $.ajax doc:

> **error**
>
> ```
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
> ```
>
> A function to be called if the request fails.  The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest)
>   object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an
>   optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the
>   second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". **When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error."**

So you can write something like:

```
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  if( errorThrown.indexOf("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") > 0 ) { 
   // success...
  }
```

The error text can also be inside `jqXHR.responseText`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ilya. Inside my `error` function I now have `alert(jqXHR.responseText);` which displays an empty alert box, so I'm assuming it's not picking up the error text?

Comment: And `jqXHR.getResponseHeader()` ?

Comment: Nothing still, that just throws the following error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: And `jqXHR.status` is zero ?

Comment: So it seems you can't tell this error appart from a "blank" error response. Maybe you can risk interpreting blank error => success, if you don't have a better option (i.e. making CORS work).